# Word_ext leads to syntax error in HANA stored procedures

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

I expect the output to be A but the invalid function name error is thrown.
The syntax appears to be correct as checked on the internet.

```
SELECT word_ext('A,B',1,',') FROM dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

**"Because the Internet said so"?**
Well, in this case, the internet is wrong, since `word_ext` neither is a standard SQL function nor one that SAP HANA provides.

The only reference to `word_ext` in the rather broad context chain of "SAP HANA" -> "SAP" -> "Data processing" I could find was in relation to a specific string manipulation function in SAP Data Services, an ETL tool.

Comment: So, that means word_ext is unavailable. What would be the substitute for it?

Comment: When you describe what `word_ext` should do for you then maybe somebody can answer this.